# Upgrading Angular version one component at a time

Tags: angular

I have an Angular app currently running Angular v11.  Is it possible to upgrade to Angular v13 one component at a time?  I know you can do this when going from AngularJS to Angular, but can you do it when upgrading the version of Angular (potentially with making the the current v11 app a library that gets imported, or maybe using web components?)

Comment: You really need to upgrade the application as a whole since that's where Angular is.  Each component runs inside of Angular, so it's not like one component can use a different version than another component.  Use this [Angular Upgrade Guide/Tool](https://update.angular.io/) to assist in upgrading your application

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to upgrade only one component at a time?